# get distance and nearest location between user location and GeoJSON(FeatureCollection)

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, backend, geojson

I need to determine if user location is valid. The valid location is determine by geoJson (FeatureCollection) with **minimum distance** from user lat and long (50 m).

The geoJson file is 7.5 Mb. Its quite big.
Here the fragment of it.
[image: geoJson Fragment]

It has many feature and coordinate.
Is there any way to achieve this with php or nodejs  ?

and if it is possible, later i need to get the closest feature and get the property name too.

Comment: You could create another array only containing the coordinates -- the index array. Have that array of coordinates follow the natural order of the original array. Then perform your computations (search) on the index array.

Comment: i have tried your suggestion. but i face another problem, i cant get the cordinate without php rounding it, i need the exact value, but whenever i try to get the coordinate, it always rounded.
example : 
 "position": "PointFromText('POINT(104.96036091408 -5.2279303804876)\\',0')",
            "x": 104.960360914076,
            "y": -5.227930380487567

$var[0] =104.960360914076
but when i use **concat** .$var[0]. =  104.96036091408 its get **rounded** 
i need the exact value ..

Comment: Why are you using "concat"? Thats forcing to a string. How about "+=" instead? Your coordinate data appears in the data structure as floats, but not string'd floats.